# geometry from relations - osm

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osmosis

Can someone show me the relevant documentation for relationships between tables?

I'm trying to get the geometry for an entry from the *relations* table but I'm unable to pick out the right information without this

Details:
schema: pgsnapshot (v0.6)
data-source: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/england/hampshire-latest.osm.pbf
db-load-command: osmosis --read-pbf ./hampshire-latest.osm.pbf --write-pgsql-dump directory=. enableBboxBuilder=yes

As far as I get:

```
select id, user_id, tags->'name' as name, tags->'admin_level' as level from relations limit 1;

   id   | user_id |   name   | level 
--------+---------+----------+-------
 108786 | 2089161 | Waverley | 8

select * from relation_members where member_id = 108786 limit 1;

 relation_id | member_id | member_type | member_role | sequence_id 
-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------
       57582 |    108786 | R           | subarea     |           4

select * from nodes where id = 57582;
 id | version | user_id | tstamp | changeset_id | tags | geom 
----+---------+---------+--------+--------------+------+------
(0 rows)

select * from ways where id = 57582;
 id | version | user_id | tstamp | changeset_id | tags | nodes 
----+---------+---------+--------+--------------+------+-------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Answers your question? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases_and_data_access_APIs

Comment: It shows a relationship between tables 'tags' and  'relation_members', but I do not have this table 'tags'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see in your relation_members table, the member_role belonging to your id ( 57582 ) is 'R'  <<-- Relation.
So your id (108786) contains another relation.

Check:
`select * from relation_members where id = 57582;`
to see if there is another relation nested within this one.

Your can select the id from the nodes or way table if the corresponding member_role is 'N' = Node or 'W' = Way

Maybe this helps a bit more:
--> http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation

Comment: Ah right, Yes thats it. (select member_id from relation_members where relation_id = 57582 and member_type = 'W') Is there any osm database documentation that would answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to check if this id (*57582*) is present in your table 'relations' ?

I'm not really used to the pgnapshot schema but i guess it should be referenced itself as a relationship in your database ?

Hope you will find (or already have) a solution to your answer!